# Can I solve the following differential equation this way?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

So I have the following differential equation of variables $M$, $v$, and $t$, where both $M$ and $v$ are functions of $t$:

$$dv = -\frac{u}{M}dM-gdt$$

where $u$ and $g$ are constants. My question is can I solve this equation by integrating each term on the right hand that has a differential (or infinitesimal) term separately like this:

$$\int dv = -\int \frac{u}{M}dM-\int gdt$$

or would does this method only work if there is only one differential on each side?

I did do it this way and according to the solutions it produces the correct answer, but to me, it still seems quite fishy. But if it is correct, is there proof that this is a legitimate method for solving differential equations that have more than 2 differential terms.

Comment: This is quite legit, you have a total differential.

Comment: Yes this is correct.

Comment: If you want to make it less "fishy", write it as
$$
v'(t) = -u\frac{M'(t)}{M(t)}-g
$$
and just take antiderivative:
$$
v(t) = -u \ln |M(t)| - gt + C.
$$